# How to fit long string in label (one line) in .NET MAUI application?

Tags: fonts, label, .net-maui

I've a label and a long string. Is there any way to calculate font size for my string to fit in label in one line?

Answer (score 0):

There a similar feature `LabelSizeFontToFit` in nuget  [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit).

For example:

```
<Label x:Name="pbText" Text=" " HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" 
    Font="{StaticResource fontAccNoCases}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
    IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference pgMain}, Path=IsBusy}" >
        <Label.Effects>
               <effects:LabelSizeFontToFit />
         </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

And I have opened a new feature in `CommunityToolkit.Maui`, you can follow it here:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/697.

Comment: It is good, but it's better to have more control of it. For example if I want to fit string in two lines.
If my ViewModel could calculate font size based on font type and string and then  apply it to the label by binding:
<Label Text=" " FontSize="{Binding MyFontSize}" />

Comment: You can first check this sample [here](https://github.com/defuncart/Xamarin/tree/master/07-AutosizeLabel).